# java stream return array of parameterized class

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, parameterized-types

Situation:

```
public class P {

    public static  Predicate<Double> isEqual(double value) {
        return p -> (Math.abs(p - value) <= 0.000001);
    }
}

public class Entity {   
    private double[] values;

    public double getValue(int index) {
        return values[index];
    }
}
```

Code with unchecked conversion:

```
public Attribute split(Entity[] examples) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    Predicate<Double>[] pa = Arrays.stream(examples).map(e -> P.isEqual(e.getValue(a.index))).toArray(Predicate[]::new);
    return ...;
}
```

How can solve this without unchecked conversion?

I can't use such:

```
public Attribute split(Entity[] examples) {
    Predicate<Double>[] pa = Arrays.stream(examples).map(e -> P.isEqual(e.getValue(a.index))).toArray(Predicate<Double>[]::new);
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: I'll let someone more knowledgeable answer, but my gut feeling is that you *cannot* do this without an unchecked conversion. Type erasure applies to array constructors, so `Predicate<Double>[]::new` does not make sense from the compiler's point of view.

Comment: I think @Chill is correct.  All the standard examples of [how to create a generic array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) that I can find rely on unchecked conversion at one point or another.

Comment: I can also note that something like `Predicate<Double>[]::new` is basically equivalent to `Function<Integer, Predicate<Double>[]> predicateMaker = (Integer size) -> new Predicate<Double>[size];`. The error here is more clear: "Cannot create a generic array of Predicate<Double>". Because you cannot create a generic array without an unchecked conversion (as @azurefrog noted in the linked page).

Comment: Generally speaking you're better off creating a list, not an array.

Comment: Louis and others, would be it better next? : Predicate<Double>[] pa = null; List<Predicate<Double>> lp = Arrays.stream(examples).map(e -> P.isEqual(e.getValue(a.index))).collect(Collectors.toList()); lp.toArray(pa);

Comment: I think best next(order not important): Predicate<Double>[] pa = null; List<Predicate<Double>> lp = Arrays.stream(examples).map(e -> P.isEqual(e.getValue(a.index))).collect(ArrayList<Predicate<Double>>::new, ArrayList<Predicate<Double>>::add, ArrayList<Predicate<Double>>::addAll); lp.toArray(pa);

Comment: You cannot use `toArray(pa)` when `pa` is `null`. That will cause a `NullPointerException`. And pre-allocating that array brings you back to square zero; creation of generic arrays is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create a generic array without unchecked conversion, as the creation of a generic array is an unsafe operation per se. Since its creation is not allowed, you can only create a non-generic array and perform an unchecked conversion.

Simply said, every operation that could enable subsequent heap pollution without any warning, must be considered an unsafe operation that either, generates a warning itself or even will produce an error. The problem can easily demonstrated:

```
Predicate<Double>[] p=/* someway to get the array*/;
Object[] array=p;
array[0]=(Predicate<Integer>)i -> i==0;
```

This situation, where an array whose elements are declared to be of type `Predicate<Double>`, but one of them is actually a `Predicate<Integer>`, is called *heap pollution*. Since both, the assignment of `p` to a variable of type `Object[]` and the assignment of a `Predicate<Integer>` to an element of an array of type `Object[]`, are legal constructs that don’t generate warnings, the creation of the array itself must be considered an unsafe operation that must generate either, a warning or an error, to prevent the subsequent silent heap pollution. Otherwise, Generics could not claim to provide compile-time safety, i.e. that code free of unchecked/unsafe operations guarantees the absence of heap pollution.

The only exception where generic array creation is accepted, is in the context of varargs, but to have a warning free code, i.e. using `@SafeVarargs`, you have to accept fundamental restrictions, e.g. you can not assign the array to any other variable nor return it from the method, to avoid a sneaky introduction of the problem described above.

So the bottom line is, either, you accept that there is an unchecked operation or you use a `List` and “use a `List`” means *use* a `List`, not try to create the array via a `List`. The fundamental difference between a `List` and an array is that you can’t assign a `List<Predicate<Double>>` to a `List<Predicate>` nor `List<Object>` (without an unchecked operation), so it provides the safety that Generics promise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually going to make my comments an answer because I found this interesting to research and I'm now pretty confident. The answer hinges on the fact (as @azurefrog noted) that creating generic arrays *must* have an unchecked conversion.

See: [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

`Predicate<Double>[]::new` would be equivalent to

```
IntFunction<Predicate<Double> []> predicateArrayMaker = (int size) -> new Predicate<Double>[size];
```

However, you cannot create a generic array without an unchecked conversion. For example,

```
Predicate<Double>[] predicateArray = new Predicate<Double>[10];
```

will have the same problem.

So, the unchecked conversion must necessarily happen as explained in the linked answer.